# What's the best way to get name and version of all packages in a packages.gz file with PHP?

Tags: php, deb, cydia

I need to get the Name and Version of all packages in a Packages file (`Packages.gz`) that's from a Cydia debian repo that I have, I'm trying to find the best way to do it in PHP.

I'm new to PHP and learning it as I go to make a small project for myself but haven't been able to find a example that I can understand. I found this while searching and it gets what I need but it's not PHP.

```
awk -F": " ' /^Package/{p=$2;getline;v=$2;getline;f=$2;ary[p"\n"v"\n"]} END{for (x in ary) print x}' file
```

Comment: quick dirty way, use `system()` or `exec()`.

Comment: Thanks probably be the only one that says anything!  Hard to get help now days..I just need a example of how to do it in php I can print the whole file out just can't figure how to get only name and version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the ZLib functions in PHP to read the file directly...

```
<?php 
error_reporting ( E_ALL );
ini_set ( 'display_errors', 1 );

$file = gzopen('Packages.gz', 'r');
while ( $line = gzgets($file))  {
    if ( substr($line, 0,8) == 'Package:' ||
            substr($line, 0,8) == 'Version:')    {
        echo $line;
    }
}
```

Comment: Great thanks a bunch I will try that!  I appreciate your time and help also for answering

Comment: Thanks Nigel I just learned something new :) I didn't know you could read the gz file without using gzdecode is what I've been using. Everything I've seen and found on searching and stuff. Thank you very much!

Comment: This is what this site is for, good to hear your learning (and not just copy past like some :)